# Tomcat not decoding the URL Encoded String

Tags: iphone, tomcat, encoding, utf-8, uri

I am Posting URL Encoded data to a jsp page (Tomcat Behind) from my iphone application (Encoded using the following method):

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc NS_AVAILABLE(10_3, 2_0);
```

And String Encoding used as parameter: NSUTF8StringEncoding

But somehow that data is incorrectly decoded.

```
Sample Text : ¥£€>€£

Encoded: %C2%A5%C2%A3%E2%82%AC%3E%E2%82%AC%C2%A3

Received on Cell As SMS: ¥ £ Φ > Φ  £
```

So, it seems that few characters are not encoded/decoded.

Any idea, what am i missing ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URI is encoded as UTF-8, but Tomcat is [decoding them as ISO-8859-1](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2). You need to edit the connector settings in the [*server.xml*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/index.html) and add the `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute.

Comment: I added this in server.xml and also set the value Charset="UTF-8" in request header, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring and are using a characterEncodingFilter, take McDowell's answer and also remember to set your url-pattern to "/*"  In my case it was set to *.do

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```